# How to know if the data can be classified in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-visualization

In classification problem, we can adjust soft margin to make things easier. However, in some cases, especially in real-world data collections, the classification problem can be extremely hard because of the noise introduced. In 2D space, the following graph can be obtained:
[image]

We can easily conclude that these two classes of data can not be classified. However, usually the features of data can be huge, which can not be plot in 2D or 3D space. I also tried TSNE to visualize the classified data. But since TSNE uses KL to train, while SVM uses loss function, I can not get anything from the following picture.

[image]

where the green ones are true positive, blue ones are false negative, yellow ones are false positive, black ones are true negative.

So my question is: is there a scientific method that can be used to analyse whether a problem can be classified or not?

Comment: What is your definition of "can be classified"?  Do you require certain low error rates.  Any two class problem can be classified if you allow high error rates.

Comment: @MichaelChernick low error rates. For example, the accuracy could be higher than 80%

Comment: So less than 20% error rate for misclassifying A as B and the same 20% for misclassifying B as A?

Comment: @MichaelChernick Yes. And cross validation is also included in evaluation.

Comment: Do you require a hard classification?  What about assigning probabilities to classes?